# re-creating this graph in excell

Tags: excel, graph, ms-word

[image]

I have to write a report but I'm stuck at drawing the graph. How can I make same graph at excell?

Answer (score 1):

I used to use a program called Datathief, worked well giving a column of x values with corresponding y values.

Here is a link: https://datathief.org/

Worked well when i needed it but not had to use it in a while, it is called Datathief III now.